# Add value to class property in the prepare segue

Tags: swift, class

For learning propose, I want to create a very simple todo app.

I make a simple model first

```
class Activity: Codable {
var title: String
var isDone: Bool

init(title: String, isDone: Bool) {
    self.title = title
    self.isDone = isDone
  }
}
```

I add `Codable` to it to use UIDocument to save the data later 
Then in the controller, I create a variable that can store an array from this class, to later use it to show the list of the activity in a `tableView`

```
 var activity = [Activity]()
```

Then, I use a popup to get a title from user and pass data back with a closure that contains the `String` of the title. Until now, everything is fine and new title is received from preparing the segue.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "new" {
        if let newTitle = segue.destination as? NewActivityPopup {
            newTitle.passData = { [weak self] title in



            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `passData` contain the string. Then I want to create a `let` property to use `Activity` to write the data.  something like that:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "new" {
        if let newTitle = segue.destination as? NewActivityPopup {
            newTitle.passData = { [weak self] title in
               let newActivity = Activity()
                 let newActivity = Activity(title: title, isDone: false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it the right way to do that? I want this title will be added to the array that I can add them into a tableview.

I want to do something like that 
1- remove init from the class
and then:

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "new" {
        if let newTitle = segue.destination as? NewActivityPopup {
            newTitle.passData = { title in
                let newActivity = Activity()
                newActivity.title = title
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but there is an error in this line:

```
  let newActivity = Activity()
```

and here is the error:

```
 Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>'
  Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call
```

Your suggestion will be a great help to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Activity class has two properties (title and isDone) and neither property has a specified default argument, so you must pass an argument of the correct type to each property. You are getting this error because you are missing isDone property's value.

One way to solve is by creating a initializer to assign the values to the properties like this:

```
init(title: String, isDone: Bool) {
   self.title = title
   self.isDone = isDone
}
```

Now while creating class instance, you should give the value to both the properties

```
let newActivity = Activity(title: "Book Writing", isDone: false)
```

Second way is:

```
let newActivity = Activity()
newActivity.title = "Book Writing"
newActivity.isDone = false
```

Or, while creating newActivity the isDone will always be false, so you can just assign false while initializing isDone property.

Comment: I want something like the second way.  In this way, I don't need to have init in the class? If no, I already test it, it shows an error: Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call - Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>'

Comment: Then initialize your isDone property like this ``` var isDone = false``` by this you are giving a default false value to isDone property and then later whenever needed you can set it to true. That's what i mentioned in last..!

Answer (score 0):

Add to Activity a custom initializer:

```
init(title: String, isDone: Bool) {
      self.title = title
      self.isDone = isDone
}
```

Then in the declaration:

```
let newActivity(title: title, isDone: false)
```